# take is not working proper with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

When i call `take` instead of `first`

```
model.associated_models.take
```

I am getting below error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method first' for nil:NilClass`from /home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@doland/gems/activerecord-`4.1.8/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:458:in find_take'
```

Sometime it works fine but sometime it does not work any reason behind it.

Comment: This is because some time you have your associate record blank, check before using 'take', record present or not  as: model.associated_models.present?, if it is true then your take will work

Comment: @GauravGupta model.associated_models.present? is true then still I am getting same error. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/19305) with activerecord versions 4.1.7 through 4.1.9.

The issue notes indicate that the problem is fixed in rails-4.1.10. If you can upgrade to 4.1.10 or above the error should go away.

If upgrading is not an option, a monkey patch is mentioned in the issue.  Stick this in an intializer:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module FinderMethods
   def find_take
      if loaded?
        @records.first if @records
      else
        @take ||= limit(1).to_a.first
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
  model.associated_models.take if model.associated_models.present?
```

Comment: model.associated_models.present? is true then still I am getting same error. thanks

Comment: try model.present? && model.associated_models.present?

Comment: please have a look answer above.

Comment: @ROR........Please update rails  version for this 4.1.10 and if you still face this problem try my logic.